# Installing software as administrator

Tags: windows-10, installation, administrator

When installing trusted software in the absence of instructions or instructions that do not indicate to install as administrator, are there any rules of thumb as for when to run the install file 'as administrator'?  Is there a best-practice?

Comment: It is helpful if a constructive comment is provided if the question is down-voted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you mean that you have programs that need elevated permissions but don't popup the elevated permissions request.

Basically I think that as a rule of thumb, don't run the program as administrator if you don't trust it.

And in general:

- If you know the program will install itself under a folder that requires permissions (Program Files).
- If it will change registry values, install services, change system settings, environment variables etc.
- If you trust the program, you can run it as administrator in the first place.

Comment: Assume the program is trusted and the program does not indicate indicate either way whether it requires installation as admin and will install in either case.  My concern is that if I install as admin, permissions may prevent other users from accessing necessary files.

Comment: I never had this situation, so it's hard to know. Usually if a program needs to be installed for all users, it will install itself in `Program Files`, meaning it will need administrative permissions for the installation. If installed only for the current user, I think mostly it won't need. I know its been a long time, but if you were wondering about a specific program, it's better to check it in a few cases and be sure about it.